# Matthew 5:23-24 Confession and forgiveness

Tags: jesus, forgiveness

> So then, if you bring your gift to the altar and there remember that your brother has something against you, leave your gift there in front of the altar. First go and be reconciled to your brother and then come and present your gift. (‭‭Matthew‬ ‭5‬:‭23‬-‭24‬ ‭NET‬‬)

Does this suggest one needs to apologize to everyone they sinned against before being fully reconciled to God?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to make it clear which way round the apology-and-forgiveness are going.

I have heard this verse preached on and even quoted as though it said "If you have something against your brother", with the moral that the gift-giver himself is obliged to go round and forgive everybody who has injured him. Despite the message of the parable, that is not what this verse says.

It is clear from the wording that the gift-giver is supposed to be repairing his own offences against other people.

Comment: Is that not what the OP is asking??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does suggest that one needs to apologize to those they have offended--and make things right with them.

Remember what Jesus also taught in the Lord's Prayer:

> And forgive us our debts, as we forgive our debtors. (Matthew 6:12,
> KJV)

If we desire to have God forgive us, we need to forgive others.  Jesus taught the same principle via a parable found in Matthew 18.

> <sup>23</sup> Therefore is the kingdom of heaven likened unto a
> certain king, which would take account of his servants.
> <sup>24</sup>And when he had begun to reckon, one was brought unto
> him, which owed him ten thousand talents.  <sup>25</sup>But forasmuch
> as he had not to pay, his lord commanded him to be sold, and his wife,
> and children, and all that he had, and payment to be made.
> <sup>26</sup>The servant therefore fell down, and worshipped him,
> saying, Lord, have patience with me, and I will pay thee all.
> <sup>27</sup>Then the lord of that servant was moved with compassion,
> and loosed him, and forgave him the debt.
>
> <sup>28</sup>But the same servant went out, and found one of his
> fellowservants, which owed him an hundred pence: and he laid hands on
> him, and took him by the throat, saying, Pay me that thou owest.
> <sup>29</sup>And his fellowservant fell down at his feet, and besought
> him, saying, Have patience with me, and I will pay thee all.
> <sup>30</sup>And he would not: but went and cast him into prison, till
> he should pay the debt.
>
> <sup>31</sup>So when his fellowservants saw what was done, they were
> very sorry, and came and told unto their lord all that was done.
> <sup>32</sup>Then his lord, after that he had called him, said unto
> him, O thou wicked servant, I forgave thee all that debt, because thou
> desiredst me:  <sup>33</sup>Shouldest not thou also have had
> compassion on thy fellowservant, even as I had pity on thee?
>
> <sup>34</sup>And his lord was wroth, and delivered him to the
> tormentors, till he should pay all that was due unto him.
> <sup>35</sup>So likewise shall my heavenly Father do also unto you, if
> ye from your hearts forgive not every one his brother their
> trespasses. (Matthew 18:23-35, KJV)

When we make things right with others, it honors God; and God will honor those who honor Him.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.  The Scripture is quite clear.  The clarity of the Gospels can be quite cutting.

John Chrysostom explains here:

> He is imposing such a necessity of reconciliation as admits of no
> excuse. For whoso hath been charged not to offer before he be
> reconciled, will hasten, if not for love of his neighbor, yet, that
> this may not lie unconsecrated, to run unto him who hath been grieved,
> and do away the enmity. For this cause He hath also expressed it all
> most significantly, to alarm and thoroughly to awaken him. Thus, when
> He had said, *Leave thy gift*, He stayed not at this, but added,
> *before the altar* (by the very place again causing him to shudder); *and go away.* And He said not merely, *Go away*, but He added,
> *first, and then come and offer thy gift.* By all these things making it manifest that this table receives not them that are at enmity with
> each other (*Homily XVI on John*).

Comment: @ user33515 This quote seems to suggest we need to make amends with those who are at enmity with rather than confessing our sins to those we sinned against. You can still be friends with your enemy without necessarily confessing exactly what you did against them.  However if your understanding is correct would this then make it prescriptive for every believer who lusted after another then be compelled to confess it?

Comment: Also what about sins that were committed in the past say 6- 25 years ago that weren’t confessed to that person? Is it still permitted to confess even if the person may  have forgetten it?

Answer (score 0):

Does Matthew 5:23-24 suggest one needs to apologize to everyone they sinned against before being fully reconciled to God? Even if this were possible, I would say that Mt 5:23-24 is more about the process of self-examination that precedes the confession or apology. “Remember that your brother has something against you” is different from saying “remember your grievance with your brother” or even “remember your offense against your brother.” “Remember that your brother has something against you” entails an examination of our actions from the perspective of those whom we may have hurt or harmed. This focus on how others perceive our actions rather than how we perceive them is demanding in that it denies us the excuses we often make for the way we treat others.

The word diallassó (διαλλάσσομαι, [Strong’s 1259](https://biblehub.com/greek/1259.htm)) occurs only once here in Mt 5:24. Generally rendered as “be reconciled,” it means “change, exchange.” In a way, it fits with the idea of putting oneself in the shoes of another. In my opinion, the reconciliation in Mt 5:24 is a recognition of sin and a change of heart that brings us to a place of repentance and contrition. It is a reconciliation with our brother in God. As such, it is more of an internal rather than an external action, one that may be carried out at any time regardless of physical or time constraints. Sometimes offenses are only realized years after the fact, when an apology is no longer practical. Ultimately, I agree with the OP that it also reconciles us to God.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of Matthew chapter 5 is the Beatitudes, so the following context would be much related to the Beatitudes that how these blessings may be achieved.

Matthew 5:21 reiterated the sixth commandment **'you shall not murder'**, and further emphasized in 5:22 that anyone who was **angry** with a brother or sister will be subject to judgement. This should recall us the first murder event in Bible, God said to Cain:

> 6 Then the Lord said to Cain, “Why are you **angry**? Why is your face downcast? 7 If you do what is right, will you not be accepted? But if you do not do what is right, sin is crouching at your door; it desires to have you, but you must rule over it.” (Genesis 4:6-7 NIV)

Therefore blessed are those who has no anger in mind.

Matthew 5:23 said someone has something against you, not specific on who was the cause. The aim is never on the person, but on how a conflict can be resolved to avoid anger set in mind became a root to sin. The following verses we see what Jesus suggested;

> 24 leave your gift there in front of the altar. First go and be **reconciled to them**; then come and offer your gift.
>
> 25 “**Settle matters quickly** with your adversary who is taking you to court. Do it while you are still together on the way, .............